# Rails 3 - Amazon S3 Paperclip EU Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using:

```
Paperclip 2.3.16
Rails 3.0.9
Ruby 1.9.2
AWS - S3 0.6.2
```

I'm trying to use paperclip the upload to the EU (Ireland) based bucket. I have the following in my model:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :grid => '90x128#', :list => '140x200#', :original => '400x548'},
            :storage => :s3,
                      :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                      :url  => 'flyers/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
                      :path => 'flyers/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
                      :bucket => 'fsight'
```

In my environment.rb I have set the write to use the AWS/s3 Default Host to the relevant EU one by using:

```
require "aws/s3"
AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST.replace "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

This works fine, and it allows me to upload the images, and I can verify the image upload / delete using the AWS Management consoler.

However, I have a problem when trying to display the images on my site. The images do not load and I have identified the cause, as the URL generated uses the old default host. Eg:

**What it should be:**
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fsight/flyers/50/full/4759543368588654950.jpg

**What it actually is:** http://s3.amazonaws.com/fsight/flyers/50/full/4759543368588654950.jpg?1314801178

As you can see, it uses the old default host.

I tried placing:

```
Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_eu_url) do |att, style|
    "#{att.s3_protocol}://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{att.bucket_name}/#{att.path(style)}"
end
```

But then started receiving the following error:

```
 wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Extracted source (around line #9):

 <img src= <%= @event.image.url(:original) %>
```

I know Paperclip has some issues with using EU Buckets, but could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try this workaround?

[Paperclip et les European S3 buckets](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/1/31/paperclip-vs-amazon-s3-european-buckets)

Or even this one?

[Paperclip, S3, and European Buckets](http://www.conandalton.net/2011/02/paperclip-s3-and-european-buckets.html)

Comment: I tried the second one, as you can see in the question. I was not aware the first one still worked, I will try it now.
Thanks for the pointer :) I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, As stated I'd tried the second one, and now I have tried the first one, both to no avail.

I can get the upload to work, but for some reason, the URL generated to fetch the image from the S3 bucket is always wrong, as stated in the question, any help?

Answer (score 31):

You don't need to work around the EU Problem anymore.

The default aws-s3 storage backend in paperclip was [replaced by the AWS SDK for Ruby](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/paperclip/commit/b67eaa7ffb2a7be5ab5f27f30934933015e4d518), that is also the amazon recommended way when working with AWS.

Just insert

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

into your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

If you want something like https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/some_path_goes_here, try to configure your model's `has_attached_file` with the following options

```
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
:s3_permissions => :private,
:s3_protocol => 'https',
:s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
:path => ":filename"
```

If you don't want to use https you can remove the `:s3_protocol` and if you want to change the region, option `:s3_host_name` is the right way to go. You can also put this into a configuration file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @toashd this really helped me out. Note also that the s3 host can be specified in your s3.yml file as `s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'`. I also had to specify `s3_endpoint: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'` to get a rake task for migrating local files working.

Answer (score 5):

I added

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

to paperclip.rb in the initializers folder and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, just solved passing the following option to **has_attached_file**:

```
:url => ':s3_domain_url'
```

For more info see here http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3 :

> Normally, this won't matter in the slightest and you can leave the default (which is path-style, or :s3_path_url). But in some cases paths don't work and you need to use the domain-style (:s3_domain_url).