# Paperclip, s3 fail to upload but didn't show any errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I've been searching for solutions in similar topics of this but I can't get it to work somehow.
This is my application log

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/0120121215-31657-19vihny.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/0120121215-31657-19vihny.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "32x32!" -     background white -flatten +matte '/tmp/0120121215-31657-19vihny20121215-31657-58mm3a.png'
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/0120121215-31657-19vihny.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/0120121215-31657-19vihny.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "320x320!" -background white -flatten +matte '/tmp/0120121215-31657-19vihny20121215-31657-1n3fgl2.png'

[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving images/:User/50cc0cfb0feea807f6000004/original.jpg
[paperclip] saving images/:User/50cc0cfb0feea807f6000004/small.png
[paperclip] saving images/:User/50cc0cfb0feea807f6000004/medium.png

Started POST "/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-15 12:39:07 +0700
Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SSjceuOzRNQfJyUCki86mNBfuHsK0bh5qQmX4pBi7uk=", "photo"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb27e0164 @original_filename="01.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image]\"; filename=\"01.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20121215-31657-9oqjbm>>, "description"=>"This is decscription"}, "commit"=>"Create Photo"}

MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (0.7489ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 INSERT       database=image12345_development collection=photos documents=[{"_id"=>"50cc0cfb0feea807f6000004", "image_file_name"=>"01.jpg", "image_content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "image_file_size"=>368812, "image_updated_at"=>2012-12-15 05:39:07 UTC, "description"=>"This is decscription"}] flags=[] (0.2658ms)

[AWS S3 200 8.971826 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"image12345",:content_length=>368812,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: 01.jpg,:key=>"images/:User/50cc0cfb0feea807f6000004/original.jpg")  

[AWS S3 200 0.214209 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"image12345",:content_length=>2763,:content_type=>"image/png",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: 0120121215-31657-19vihny20121215-31657-58mm3a.png,:key=>"images/:User/50cc0cfb0feea807f6000004/small.png")  

[AWS S3 200 3.498196 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"image12345",:content_length=>142791,:content_type=>"image/png",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: 0120121215-31657-19vihny20121215-31657-1n3fgl2.png,:key=>"images/:User/50cc0cfb0feea807f6000004/medium.png")  

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/photos/50cc0cfb0feea807f6000004
Completed 302 Found in 12992ms
```

I use **devise** for user

In my gem file There's

```
gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"
gem 'paperclip'
gem "aws-sdk"
```

In my models/photo.rb

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :image,
:path           => ':attachment/:User/:id/:style.:extension',
:storage        => :s3,
:s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml'), #s3.yml contain credentials
:styles => {
:small => ['32x32!', :png],
:medium   => ['320x320!',    :png, :jpg],

},
:convert_options => { :all => '-background white -flatten +matte' }  
attr_accessible :image, :description
```

in my form

```
<%= form_for(@photo , :html => {:multipart => true} ) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I've already tried many solutions like add form_helper :multipart and in my previous applications, this model and gem worked finely and I'm sure that the credential is correct.  it's just told me that it's a success update but no image is uploaded.
Where can I look for an errors on this issue? or any tools I can use ? I'm really stuck on this and want to get through it, not creating new app and wish for luck.

Answer (score 0):

Already found the solution sometime ago but forget to post

it's the same problem at this question
[Rails 3 - Amazon S3 Paperclip EU Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257745/rails-3-amazon-s3-paperclip-eu-problem)

figured it out when I see a picture has already been uploaded but it's just I didn't use the right address to access them :)