# Ruby on Rails, Paperclip, Amazon AWS S3 & Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I try for two days to make my all web site work on the internet through Heroku and Amazon AWS S3 ( to store my images ) but ... I can't make it !

To make it simplier, I would like to use Heroku and Amazon AWS S3 with paperclip just to upload a picture and show it.

I followed a lot of tutorial but, this one sum up all I did : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

The upload system work well with the basic storage in local but if I follow the tutorial and put this code in my environment I have errors

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

First my code and then I will write the error I have in local and the one I have when I try to test in the Internet ( Heroku open ).

My code :

**develpment.rb :**

```
Blabla::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
    }

end
```

**production.rb :**

```
Blabla::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}

end
```

**herocu config :**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:          AKI********************
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:      Aiqpdg******************
DATABASE_URL:     **************************
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL: ***********************
KOIDEPLOY_TOKEN:            ********************
S3_BUCKET_NAME:             pylo*****
```

**my initializer paperclip.rb :**

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

**ERROR When I try locally :**

I can upload the picture but when I submit :

```
ArgumentError in PhotosController#create
missing required :bucket option


respond_to do |format|
```

**ERROR when I try in the internet with the "heroku open" command :**

I can chose a file but when I submit :

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

Please help me :)

**Edit :** 
On my AWS S3 account I just created a bucket on the eu aera. 
I succed to see my website on heroku, the problem is the upload

**My photo model : photo.rb :**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :image
end
```

**My show.erb.html file :**

```
<% if @photo.image? %>
    <%= image_tag @photo.image.url %>

<% end %>
```

[image: what the show page give]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this problem before!

Solved it by putting the bucket vars in the model itself (live code):

```
 #app/models/image.rb
 has_attached_file :image,
                :styles => { :medium => "x300", :thumb => "x100" },
                :default_url => "**********",
                :storage => :s3,
                :bucket => '*****',
                :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS

 #config/application.rb
 config.paperclip_defaults = {
            :storage => :s3,
            :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
 }

 #config/initializers/s3.rb
 if Rails.env == "production"
     # set credentials from ENV hash
 S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'], :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'], :bucket => "*****"}
 else
     # get credentials from YML file
     S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
 end

#config/application.yml ([figaro][1] gem)
S3_KEY: ********
S3_SECRET: **********
```

We also have this in our production.rb:

```
#app/environments/production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

The `ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']` is the bucket name, and there's also one for different regions. [Here's a very good resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257745/rails-3-amazon-s3-paperclip-eu-problem) for you (the answer with 15 upvotes... not the accepted answer)

Comment: Ok, I try but what is the default_url ?

Comment: default_url is if it's missing. We used a demo one, but you can put anything you want in there. The S3 credentials are constants. According to [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3), you should store your details in the Heroku environment variables, and we just put the dev ones into a local "s3.yml" file (I updated the answer to include it)

Comment: ok it seems to work because I can see the pictures in my bucket on AWS S3 but my show page when I submit the picture just give me the name of the file and know show me the picture ! (I edit my question to show you the code)

Comment: Might sound strange, but can you take a screenshot of what the `show.html.erb` is coming back with? It would be great if we could see it

Comment: I just edit it ! This is the result when I upload a file named 555.png

Comment: Hmm okay - if you hover over that item, is it an image (with the alt tag showing), or is it just text?

Comment: yes it's an image and I can saw it on AWS S3, but im wondering if I give the AWS S3 url of the image ( which is https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pyloriruc/photos/images/000/000/048/original/555.png) 
Something like <%= image_tag https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pyloriruc/photos/images/000/000/048/original/@photo.image.url %> ? 
Do you think it's a good idea ?

Comment: The image exists (it's a BUNNY!), which is a good sign. If you uploaded this through Paperclip, it's an even better sign! I think the problem will be how you're calling the image. Maybe if you try `<%= image_tag @photo.image.url(:original) %>` ?

Comment: No it doesn't work but I seach in the web develloper in firefox and I saw the html code of the show page. 

The code for the image is :
 
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/pyloriruc/photos/images/000/000/053/original/555.png" alt="555"></img>

and the url of the image in amazon aws S3 is :
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pyloriruc/photos/images/000/000/048/original/555.png

so the code in my show page is the same but without the region "-eu-west-1" so how can I put it ?

Comment: Did you try adding this to your `application.rb`:
` config.paperclip_defaults = {
            :storage => :s3,
            :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
 }` ?

Comment: We also have this in our `production.rb`:
`config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"`

Comment: Ok ! It finally work, I add ":s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'" to the photo model ! Thank you for the link and you help ! 
But I have an other problem ... Everything work perfectly on my localhost ( the server is local but store and show the image from amazon) but when I comit it and test it through heroku I have the same issue : I can chose the picture but after I have the "Something went wrong, please see the heroku logs". Besides, when I cheek on the aws s3, when I try through heroku the picture is not even there !

Answer (score 1):

Try this url. this will give you a help.

http://www.peoplecancode.com/en/tutorials/uploading-images-on-heroku-saving-to-aws-s3-using-fog

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `Photo` class?

From the logs

```
Paperclip::Error (Photo model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'):
```

It looks to me like you don't have the `has_attached_file` defined on your class.

From the tutorial you linked:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  # You will need to use attr_accessible if you are
  # using Rails config setting `whitelist_attributes = true`
  attr_accessible :avatar

  # This method associates the attribute ":avatar" with a file attachment
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
 }
end
```

If you do have this (or something similar) then you probably need to make a migration to get that column in your database:

```
add_attachment :photos, :image
```

Which will add the correct columns to your `photos` table.

With the `has_attached_file` and the columns on your table, I don't think you should have any (or at least the same) problems

Comment: I have the has_attached_file in my photo model : class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :image
end

Comment: Beside, my code works when I want to upload a file directly in my local database but not when I want to use the heroku temp database or Amazon S3