# Heroku S3 Paperclip Doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm having issue with paperclip and heroku and really need help.I've lost the past 2 days getting stuck on this and none of the link i could found helped :

```
https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/paperclip-aws"
"http://www.codeitive.com/0QHVXqkUVV/heroku-paperclip-s3-error-%3E-    awss3errorssignaturedoesnotmatch.html"
"https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#international-users-additional-configuration"
"http://dchua.com/2011/12/27/how-to-get-paperclip-and-aws-s3-singapore-and-european-buckets-working/"
"http://www.kahfei.com/?p=389"
"http://www.conandalton.net/2011/02/paperclip-s3-and-european-buckets.html"
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424724/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-amazon-aws-s3-heroku"
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257745/rails-3-amazon-s3-paperclip-eu-problem"
```

---

In the beginning i wanted to use an european S3 location but since it seems to make everything more complicated i've decided to switch back to the default US location.

I've setup my VARS as follow on terminal :

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
```

Then inside my config/environment/production.rb :

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

When going to my website and trying to upload a picture my heroku log is as follow :

```
Running `bundle exec rake db:seed` attached to terminal... up, run.8070
rake aborted!
AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:375:in `return_or_raise'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:476:in `client_request'
(eval):3:in `put_object'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:1765:in `write_with_put_object'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:611:in `write'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.2.1/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:360:in `block in flush_writes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.2.1/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:331:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.2.1/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:331:in `flush_writes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.2.1/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:238:in `save'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-meta-1.2.0/lib/paperclip-meta/attachment.rb:16:in `save_with_meta_data'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.2.1/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:91:in `block in add_active_record_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:225:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:225:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/app/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Obviously i've double checked my heroku configs and trying to input both key and bucket again => no change.

At this point i've tried so many stuff that i'm at lost.
Setting heroku stuff inside my model after attached_files 
Setting heroku YAML file in addition to heroku config var
Tried both european and us standard buckets

If anyone has any idea.. All the research i did on that error didn't help one bit :  `AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

Comment: Does it work locally? Which version of paperclip are you using? I know you said you double checked your `heroku config`, but double check again that you haven't swapped your access key id and secret key... :)

Comment: I didn't try locally no.Thought it would be way more straightforward. I'm doing it now and having 'missing required :bucket option'
I guess that's something to look into.
It's strange tho, i have seen that error again and again on stackoverflow while trying to fix my issue , but first time i see it. I suspect it's coming from my local configuration rather than having anything to do with the other error.

Comment: Ok just go it to work locally

Comment: Good, now you can push live

Comment: Yes, it's working live. But it's no where near what heroku paperclip tutorial said.

Comment: Glad you figured out then!

Answer (score 1):

Ok just go it working so for the next person having that issue :

-Don't follow the heroku paperclip tutorial

-Create a aws.yml file in your config folder with inside :

```
development:
  access_key_id: "xxxxxinquote"
  secret_access_key: "yyyyyinquote"
test:
  access_key_id: abc...
  secret_access_key: abc...
production:
  access_key_id: "xxx"
  secret_access_key: "yyyy"
```

-Inside all your models with file upload put :

```
has_attached_file :image,
                  :styles => { :medium => "460x>", :thumb => "100x100>",:vnice=> "400x" },
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :bucket => 'hohohohoho',
                  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml",
                  :path => "resources/:id/:style/:basename.:extension
```

Then inside your production or/and dev.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Note : :bucket is OUTSIDE the s3 credentials unlike what is said in the tutorial.

Hope it can help someone

Comment: I'm having an issue with paperclip and heroku right now. I'll be sure to try this later.